# get regex from antlr grammar

Tags: regex, token, antlr, ace-editor

there is a way to get regexes from an antlr grammar file? I have a langage grammar and I need token regexes to make an ace editor?

thanks in advance

Comment: maybe translate your antlr grammar into this ? https://github.com/foo123/ace-grammar/

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Build a parser for ANTLR grammars (ANTLR itself in fact already does this) that constructs a tree for the regexps.

You'll still have to *translate* those regexps into a form compatible for your ACE editor.    Such a project is likely to take you days.

I think the effort to do this likely exceeds the cost to simply convert the regexes by hand.  [I already said this to you once.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35378068/120163)